# Why does Map<String,List> List update fail?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have comments variable which is dictionary type and holds the second parameter as a list
Unfortunately, despite I get the data (inputDataSnapshot) I can not get it added to the dictionary. The dictionary with the relevant key always return null
Can someone please help why this happens?

````
  Map<String?, List<Commentp?>?>? comments;

  int _pageIndex = 0;
  int _limit = 3;

  String get pageIndex {
    return _pageIndex.toString();
  }

  String get limit {
    return _limit.toString();
  }

  List<Commentp?>? commentsP({required String postuuid}) {
    return comments?[postuuid] ?? [];
  }

  void add({
    required String postuuid,
    required List inputDataSnapshot,
  }) {
    for (int i = 0; i < inputDataSnapshot.length; i++) {
      comments?[postuuid]!.add(Commentp.fromJson(inputDataSnapshot[i]));
      print(comments?[postuuid]);
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: Do you ever initialize `comments`?

Comment: exactly the point, already solved :)

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I made was uninitialized comments variable.
I added below code to my add method and it is fine now

```
if (comments[postuuid] == null) {
      comments[postuuid] = [];
    }
```

Comment: This can be simplified to `(comments[postuuid] ??= []).add(...)` which avoids looking up `comments[postuuid]` multiple times.

Comment: very nice, thanks!